# Django Form error: expected string or bytes-like object for datetime object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a very simple django form for renting out keys that defaults a due date for the user, the user can change the date and then go on and save the form. However whenever I save the `key_instance`, django throws a `error: expected string or bytes-like object`. I know the datetime object is causing this error because if i comment it out everything works fine. Here is my views.py and forms.py

forms.py:

```
class UpdateKeyRequestForm(forms.Form):

    APPROVE_CHOICES = [
        ('d', 'Deny this key request'),
        ('a', 'Approve this key request')

    ]

    request_status = forms.CharField(label='Please select to accept or deny this request.',widget=forms.Select(choices=APPROVE_CHOICES))

    due_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Enter a date (YYYY-MM-DD) between now and 4 weeks (default 3). ')

    def clean_due_date(self):
        due_date = self.cleaned_data['due_date']
        approved_status = self.cleaned_data['request_status']

        # Check date is not in past.
        if due_date < datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - renewal in past'))
        if due_date > datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=4):
            raise ValidationError(_('Invalid date - renewal more than 4 weeks ahead'))


        return due_date, approved_status
```

views.py:

```
@permission_required('catalog.can_mark_returned')
def update_key_request(request, pk):
    """
    View function for renewing a specific keyInstance by admin
    """
    key_inst=get_object_or_404(KeyInstance, pk=pk)


    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        form = UpdateKeyRequestForm(request.POST)

        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required (here we just write it to the model due_back field)
            request_status = form.cleaned_data['request_status']
            due_date = form.cleaned_data['due_date']
            if request_status == 'a':
                key_inst.due_back = due_date
                key_inst.status = 'o'
                key_inst.date_out = datetime.date.today()
                key_inst.save()
            else:
                key_inst.status = 'a'
                key_inst.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-available-keys'))
    else:
        default_due_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
        form = UpdateKeyRequestForm(initial={'due_date': default_due_date})

    #If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.

    return render(request, 'catalog/roomkey_request_update.html', {'form': form, 'keyinst': key_inst})
```

But the thing is I implemented this exact logic with the exact same method to update the due date and it's still working fine. I am very confused as to why this one throws an error. Can anyone please shed some light?

Here is my local var on the error page:

```
due_date    
(datetime.date(2018, 6, 13),)
form    
<UpdateKeyRequestForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(due_date)>
key_inst    
<KeyInstance: Conestogo River (3fc9458a-5ec8-46a3-a04e-6a48e650b15f)>
pk  
UUID('3fc9458a-5ec8-46a3-a04e-6a48e650b15f')
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/catalog/key/3fc9458a-5ec8-46a3-a04e-6a48e650b15f/update'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clean_due_date` method should only return the `due_date`.

```
def clean_due_date(self):
    ...
    return due_date
```

You don't appear to use `approved_status` in that method, so I would remove this line from the method

```
approved_status = self.cleaned_data['request_status']
```

If you do need to [clean fields that rely on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), then you should do that in the `clean()` method instead of a `clean_<fieldname>` method.